# Database copy larger than original

Tags: linux, database, centos

I just created a backup of my database using command mysqldump in Centos7. Then recreated the database for making a copy of the current website for development purposes. But i noticed the size of the copy is higher than the original database. By almost 70MB. Any idea why?

Comment: What commands did you use? What was the original database size? 40Mb to 130Mb is very different from 1Gb to 1.07Gb

Comment: Very low differences like 70Mb can be just tags related to patch or version etc... even comments if the dump has not been compressed, like timestampe for example.